# Mercurial: which config property controls the encoding of file contents?

Tags: file, encoding, character-encoding, mercurial

Is there a dedicated Mercurial configuration property which specifies the encoding of file contents and hence should be used by a Mercurial client to properly display a file?

I've found `web.encoding` which does not seem to mean exactly what I'm looking for. Also, Google gave some results for `ui.encoding` as well, but I couldn't find any hints in the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial is not concerned with the encoding of the files you put in your repository: Mercurial is happy to store files with any encoding (or maybe not particular encoding at all).

This means that you can add files with UTF-8, Latin-1, or any other encoding to your repository and Mercurial will check them out exactly as they were when you added them.

The encoding of each file is not stored anywhere in Mercurial and it is up to the client to recognize the encoding (perhaps based on file content where it makes sense, e.g., for XML files).

For a Mercurial desktop client (as per your comments below) I suggest looking at the file content:

1. Can you decode it at UTF-16?
2. Can you decode it as UTF-8?
3. Are the `NUL` bytes in the file? Then stop and declare it to be "binary".
4. Fallback on a Latin-N encoding such as Latin-1 for Western Europe.

The UTF-16 and UTF-8 encodings are nice since they are structured and this makes it possible for you to detect that a file *isn't* valid UTF-8 encoded, say. The above list is written with a European perspective — you should probably also consult someone with knowledge about Shift JIS and other encodings used in Asia.

In any case, I would only expect a Mercurial client to do a best effort attempt at showing me a file with an encoding other than ASCII.

---

Some alternative interpretations of your question:

- If you're really asking about how to make your files look "correct" when you view them in `hgweb`, then it's a matter of using a consistent encoding in the repository and [setting `web.encoding](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Indicating_the_encoding_of_served_content).
- If you're really asking how to ensure that text files get the OS native line ending character on different platforms (`\n` on Unix, `\r\n` on Windows) when take a look at the [eol extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension) that comes with Mercurial.

Comment: When writing a desktop Mercurial client, would you use `web.encoding` as well when displaying file contents? Or would you introduce some new setting in .hg/hrgc (or ~/.hgrc)?

Comment: I would make the client try `UTF-8` first and then fallback on `Latin-1`, or just feed the bytes from the file to whatever widget you have for displaying text. Such widgets will often display a special glyph for bytes that cannot be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

No. Encoding (charset) is property of file in repository

Comment: And where is this property stored in the repository?

Comment: @mstrap - nowhere. It's property of file, always exist in file and only in file

Comment: Where and how does the encoding "exist in the file"? In Subversion, you have (global) property `svn:mime-type`. In Git you have `gui.encoding`. What do you have in Mercurial?

Comment: The `svn:mime-type` property may be missing or incorrect: I can add PNG image and give it the mime type of a JPEG image.